# Why does std::bind not adapt function signatures?

Tags: c++

I'm about to tear my hair out. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or fundamentally misunderstanding what `std::bind` is for. I am calling this function:

```
void fetch(Face& face,
           const Interest& baseInterest,
           shared_ptr<Validator> validator,
           const CompleteCallback& completeCallback,
           const ErrorCallback& errorCallback);
```

like this:

```
ndn::util::SegmentFetcher::fetch(
  m_nlsrFace,
  interest,
  m_validator,
  [&datasetBlob](const ndn::ConstBufferPtr& data){
    datasetBlob = data;
  },
  std::bind(&Nlsr::onFaceDatasetFetchTimeout,
            _1, _2, datasetBlob, interest));
```

And the signature for `ErrorCallback` is like this:

```
typedef function<void (uint32_t code, const std::string& msg)> ErrorCallback;
```

The error that is being thrown at me is this:

```
/usr/local/include/ndn-cxx/util/segment-fetcher.hpp:141:3: note:
  no known conversion for argument 5 from ‘
    std::_Bind_helper<
      false,
      void (nlsr::Nlsr::*)(unsigned int,
                           const std::basic_string<char>&,
                           const std::shared_ptr<const ndn::Buffer>&,
                           ndn::Interest),
      const std::_Placeholder<1>&,
      const std::_Placeholder<2>&,
      std::shared_ptr<const ndn::Buffer>&,
      ndn::Interest&>::type
  {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (nlsr::Nlsr::*)(
                                 unsigned int,
                                 const std::basic_string<char>&,
                                 const std::shared_ptr<const ndn::Buffer>&,
                                 ndn::Interest)>
                    (std::_Placeholder<1>,
                     std::_Placeholder<2>,
                     std::shared_ptr<const ndn::Buffer>,
                     ndn::Interest)>}’
  to ‘const ErrorCallback&
  {aka const std::function<void(unsigned int, const std::basic_string<char>&)>&}’
```

I just don't understand what the issue is. I am binding the function to have the right number of parameters (and of the right type, too!) and fixing the others. But it seems that `std::bind` doesn't change the function signature, because I appear to be having issues with type resolution. What then is the use of `std::bind`? I am using it incorrectly?

Comment: Where is the `this` pointer supposed to come from? On what object are you expecting `onFaceDatasetFetchTimeout` to be invoked (or is it a `static` function)?

Comment: Tried to reformat your code/error output a bit (linebreaks/indentation), hope it is more readable now.

Comment: @mindriot You are a wizard, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Nlsr::onFaceDatasetFetchTimeout` is non `static`, you have to bind the instance of `Nlsr` to it (at first argument).

```
std::bind(&Nlsr::onFaceDatasetFetchTimeout,
          myNlsrObject,
          _1, _2, datasetBlob, interest)
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about this. That was decidedly the problem, but a further question, is why can't the compiler check for that? As in, why can't it check to see if the function I'm calling is a member method and then just assume a default "this" if I've not included anything that's a class. Seems very silly to me.

Comment: @Bronze: `bind` has no access to a magical default `this`. Some compilers have a more useful message, something like: *"error: static_assert failed "Wrong number of arguments for pointer-to-member""*